# Using Java regex want to match only & but not &amp; &lt; etc

Tags: java, regex

Using Java regex pattern I want to match the `&` symbol. But it should not match `&amp;`, `&lt;` etc... (HTML encoding).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
&(?![A-Za-z]+;|#[0-9]+;)
```

This matches an `&` that's not followed by one or more ASCII letters and a `;` or a hash symbol, followed by one or more ASCII digits and a ";".

Comment: But i want to match the url containing like this. http://abc.com?ac=45&df=def  to http://abc.com?ac=45&amp;df=def

Comment: OK; I've proposed an alternative that will work in your case.

Comment: @Kobi: Thanks! I added this into my answer.

Comment: Tim, that's awesome, but per this reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references there's also a hexadecimal form, so maybe the full regex would be: `&(?![A-Za-z]+;|#[0-9]+;|#x[0-9a-fA-F]+;)`  Seems to work right for me: http://rubular.com/r/3DPJTH3m4M

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Regex is the right way to go for this problem. Maintain a list of all the HTML encodings you want to remove. Preprocess the text and remove all such occurrences and then check for '&'.

Comment: What if the OP wants *all* entities, including invalid/future ones? The `&#123;` syntax allows all characters anyway...

Comment: @Kobi: Yeah in that case Tim's solution would be a better fit. But if he just wants to remove a set of encodings, regex would result in a lot of false positives.